# display last 5days date in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to display last 5 days date. But it display only last date(yesterday). I am using the following code to display it.

.h file:

```
NSInteger getDist;
NSString *lastdate;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
NSDate *sevenDaysAgo;
NSDate *dateAfterDecrement;
NSString *dateString;
int i;
```

viewDidLoad:

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YY"];
dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
_currentDate.text=dateString;

-(void)display
{
  for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
  {
    lastdate = _currentDate.text;
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YY"];
    sevenDaysAgo = [dateFormatter dateFromString:lastdate];
    dateAfterDecrement=[sevenDaysAgo initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-
    (24*60*60)];
    }
    _currentDate.text =  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateAfterDecrement];

}
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: Assuming that `currentDate` is a @property use `self.currentDate`, not `_currentDate`. Using `_currentDate` is not an error but using `self.currentDate` is the current Best Practice. It also allows setting a breakpoint on the property and breaking on access. It also allows the property to be changed in the future to a method that returns a calculated value.

Comment: still it display only yesterday date.

Comment: For loop will run 5 times and display last loop value i.e;i=4 value. So it is displaying only yesterday value everytime try to save the values getting from each for loop...So.._currentDate.text is displaying last for loop value

Comment: The code doesn't come close to compiling. Among other things there are no variable declarations for: `dateFormatter`, `dateString`, `i`, `last date`, `sevenDaysAgo`, `dateAfterDecrement`. Additionally `sevenDaysAgo initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:` is incorrect, that is a method to be used with alloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to display today's date, then the last 4 days' dates.

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

int DAY_TO_SECONDS = -60*60*24;
for (int n=0; n<5; n++)
{
    NSDate* date = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:DAY_TO_SECONDS*n];
    NSString* dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
}
```

This produces output like:

```
2015-02-23 13:18:30.657 ClientInfo[1418:557691] Feb 23, 2015
2015-02-23 13:18:30.658 ClientInfo[1418:557691] Feb 22, 2015
2015-02-23 13:18:30.658 ClientInfo[1418:557691] Feb 21, 2015
2015-02-23 13:18:30.658 ClientInfo[1418:557691] Feb 20, 2015
2015-02-23 13:18:30.658 ClientInfo[1418:557691] Feb 19, 2015
```

Comment: I am getting the following error. no known class method for selector "now".

Comment: Sorry, I had added this myself.  I've changed my code to make it [NSDate date].

Answer (score 1):

you can decrement current date to this way by the number of days you want to get

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar]; 
    NSDateComponents *datecomponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit
                        | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                        fromDate:[NSDate date]];
             for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
              NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:datecomponents];
              NSLog(@"%@",date);
              --datecomponents.day;
             }
```